# Provisioning a Windows VM in Azure with WinRM port (5986) open

Tags: azure, terraform, winrm

I'm trying to provision a windows vm on Azure with Terraform with the port 5986 open to allow winrm access. The provisioning of the VM works.

I'm stuck on opening the port with terraform during provisioning. Any ideas?

Comment: What have you tried to do to open the port? And if there's an error can you edit your question to include it exactly as well?

Comment: You should post your code here.

Comment: Please post your code here with the error if you are getting any so it would allow others to determine where you are stuck.

Answer (score 2):

You can follow the terraform script to create a windows server 2016 datacenter and open the default RDP port 3389 and port 5986 in NSG. It works for me.

```
Terraform v0.11.8
+ provider.azurerm v1.14.0
+ provider.random v2.0.0
```

The full sample

```
variable "resourcename" {
  default = "myResourceGroup"
}

# Configure the Microsoft Azure Provider
provider "azurerm" {
    subscription_id = "xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
    client_id       = "xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
    client_secret   = "xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
    tenant_id       = "xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
}

# Create a resource group if it doesn’t exist
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "myterraformgroup" {
    name     = "myResourceGroup"
    location = "eastus"

    tags {
        environment = "Terraform Demo"
    }
}

# Create virtual network
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "myterraformnetwork" {
    name                = "myVnet"
    address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
    location            = "eastus"
    resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.myterraformgroup.name}"

    tags {
        environment = "Terraform Demo"
    }
}

# Create subnet
resource "azurerm_subnet" "myterraformsubnet" {
    name                 = "mySubnet"
    resource_group_name  = "${azurerm_resource_group.myterraformgroup.name}"
    virtual_network_name = "${azurerm_virtual_network.myterraformnetwork.name}"
    address_prefix       = "10.0.1.0/24"
}

# Create public IPs
resource "azurerm_public_ip" "myterraformpublicip" {
    name                         = "myPublicIP"
    location                     = "eastus"
    resource_group_name          = "${azurerm_resource_group.myterraformgroup.name}"
    public_ip_address_allocation = "dynamic"

    tags {
        environment = "Terraform Demo"
    }
}

# Create Network Security Group and rule
resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "myterraformnsg" {
    name                = "myNetworkSecurityGroup"
    location            = "eastus"
    resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.myterraformgroup.name}"

    security_rule {
        name                       = "RDP"
        priority                   = 1001
        direction                  = "Inbound"
        access                     = "Allow"
        protocol                   = "Tcp"
        source_port_range          = "*"
        destination_port_range     = "3389"
        source_address_prefix      = "*"
        destination_address_prefix = "*"
    }

  security_rule {
        name                       = "WinRM"
        priority                   = 998
        direction                  = "Inbound"
        access                     = "Allow"
        protocol                   = "Tcp"
        source_port_range          = "*"
        destination_port_range     = "5986"
        source_address_prefix      = "*"
        destination_address_prefix = "*"
    }


    tags {
        environment = "Terraform Demo"
    }
}

# Create network interface
resource "azurerm_network_interface" "myterraformnic" {
    name                      = "myNIC"
    location                  = "eastus"
    resource_group_name       = "${azurerm_resource_group.myterraformgroup.name}"
    network_security_group_id = "${azurerm_network_security_group.myterraformnsg.id}"

    ip_configuration {
        name                          = "myNicConfiguration"
        subnet_id                     = "${azurerm_subnet.myterraformsubnet.id}"
        private_ip_address_allocation = "dynamic"
        public_ip_address_id          = "${azurerm_public_ip.myterraformpublicip.id}"
    }

    tags {
        environment = "Terraform Demo"
    }
}

# Generate random text for a unique storage account name
resource "random_id" "randomId" {
    keepers = {
        # Generate a new ID only when a new resource group is defined
        resource_group = "${azurerm_resource_group.myterraformgroup.name}"
    }

    byte_length = 8
}

# Create storage account for boot diagnostics
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "mystorageaccount" {
    name                        = "diag${random_id.randomId.hex}"
    resource_group_name         = "${azurerm_resource_group.myterraformgroup.name}"
    location                    = "eastus"
    account_tier                = "Standard"
    account_replication_type    = "LRS"

    tags {
        environment = "Terraform Demo"
    }
}

# Create virtual machine
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "myterraformvm" {
    name                  = "myVM"
    location              = "eastus"
    resource_group_name   = "${azurerm_resource_group.myterraformgroup.name}"
    network_interface_ids = ["${azurerm_network_interface.myterraformnic.id}"]
    vm_size               = "Standard_DS1_v2"

    storage_os_disk {
        name              = "myOsDisk"
        caching           = "ReadWrite"
        create_option     = "FromImage"
        managed_disk_type = "Premium_LRS"
    }

    storage_image_reference {
        publisher = "MicrosoftWindowsServer"
        offer     = "WindowsServer"
        sku       = "2016-Datacenter"
        version   = "latest"
    }

    os_profile {
        computer_name  = "myvm"
        admin_username = "azureuser"
        admin_password = "Password1234!"
    }

    os_profile_windows_config {
       enable_automatic_upgrades = false
  }

    boot_diagnostics {
        enabled = "true"
        storage_uri = "${azurerm_storage_account.mystorageaccount.primary_blob_endpoint}"
    }

    tags {
        environment = "Terraform Demo"
    }
}
```